# Match() function only runs for 0, but not for other values

Tags: r

I use Time Series data (imported with `read.csv()`) and want to `match()` values from an other data frame (also imported with `read.csv`) to those recorded in my Time Series. 
It looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(hue=rawdata[,"hue"])
# This is my Time Series-raw data
                    hue
2017-07-01 00:00:00   0
2017-07-01 00:01:00   0
2017-07-01 00:02:00   0
2017-07-01 00:03:00   0
2017-07-01 00:04:00   0
2017-07-01 00:05:00   0
```

The Values change between 0 and 7 sometimes. Here's just a `head()` print

And this is the data frame I want to check it with:

```
df2 <- data.frame(hue=sz$hue, Q=sz$Q)
# sz is the imported csv file
  hue  Q
1   0  0
2   1 13
3   2 26
4   3 39
5   4 52
6   5 65
```

Here, the same: Just a `head()` print.

Now, **my aim is** to create a new column next to `hue` in my rawdata.
in this new column I want the `Q`-values depending on their `hue` of `df2`. For example: From minute Zero to five on 2017-07-01 the `Q`-value in the new column will be 0, because `hue` is 0.

I tried many things with the `match` function like:

```
df1$match=sz$Q[match(df1$hue, sz$hue)]
```

But it's only working for the 0's and not for other values like 1,2,3 etc. R only gives me `NA`s at those points.

It works perfectly in this Video:
[Using Match function in R](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FjgGxm9sww)

Actually I'm not quite sure if this is really a "match"-problem or a more format problem because I checked these two things:

```
> df1["2017-07-21 23:20:00","hue"]==2 # the value at this date is actually 2!
[1] FALSE
> is.numeric(df1["2017-07-21 23:20:00","hue"])
[1] TRUE
```

Does anyone know what I can do to get R to consider all values?
Thank you so much for taking time for this!

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. See [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248) for what this would mean in R. For example, if you want to ask about `df1`, post the results of `dput(head(df1))`

Comment: Hi John Coleman, yes, sorry for that. Here is an extract of my time series, that shows two diffrent values (0,2): `> dput(head(df1))
structure(list(hue = c(1.99999999999818, 1.99999999999818, 0)), .Names = "hue", row.names = c("2017-07-21 23:24:00", 
"2017-07-21 23:25:00", "2017-07-21 23:26:00"), class = "data.frame")`
I wonder why these numbers are that strange and not '2' actually :/

Comment: I fixed it! It isn't a `match`problem. The solution is to `round` my df1 while matching it with df2 like: `df1$match=df2$Q[match(round(df1$hue), df2$hue)]`. Before, the values could not match because 1,999818 is, obviously, not the same like 2.